# Centar un elemento dentro de un DIV

Tags: html, css

Tengo varios elementos `SPAN` dentro de un elemento `div`, y quiero los `SPAN` se puedan alinear al centro.

```
<div class="center">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Para alinear al centro los **<span>** dependerá del tamaño del contenedor padre, eso se puede hacer con display **flex** por ejemplo, adjunta el código HTML y CSS del intento que has realizado, de lo contrario cerraran tu pregunta.

Comment: al div le puedes poner el CSS display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; eso si quieres que esten como en "la misma linea" si quieres que esten como en líneas diferentes crea puros div en lugar de span y ponles la clase "center".
El DIV por defecto toma el 100% del ancho de su contenedor padre, los span no

Comment: Te recomendamos subir si puedes algún ejemplo quiza hasta dibujo de la estructura que quieres que tengan tu resultados